# Excel connectivity to s3 through REST API can read files in bucket root but not in folders of bucket

Tags: excel, rest, amazon-s3

I have json/text/csv files stored inside a s3 bucket. Some of are on root, other ones are inside a folder.

This bucket is exposed through an API which requires key.

In Excel, I create a connection to web source, with API url + path to file
**i.e. https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myAPIstage/mys3bucket/myfile1.txt**
and it works fine.

However, when I try to reach a file part of a s3 folder, it does not work and I receive "forbidden" error message what means it does not reach the target...
**i.e. https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myAPIstage/mys3bucket/myfolder/myfile1.txt**

*A colleague says it's because slash is not understood by API, as if this character wasn't well encoded.
I tried to replace by %2f but it doesn't change anything.*

Comment: Which slashes did you encode?  If you're using an API Gateway REST endpoint, as suggested by the URL here, then it should be something like `https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myAPIstage/mys3bucket/myfolder%2Fmyfile1.txt`

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately unsuccessful

Comment: Not that https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myAPIstage/mys3bucket/myfolder%2Fmyfile1.txt works fine when I test API in API Gateway. Problem is Excel related